# android TabsHost is not showing inside a Fragment using SDK 22

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

i am new to android, my question is when i put a `TabHost` inside a `Fragment` its not showing after running my app! i am not sure i am doing it in a right way ! or some part of code is missing.here is my codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
package com.hesabgar.hesabgar;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

    public FindPeopleFragment(){}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
  // What should i put here ? ?? ? ??
        return rootView;
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_tabs);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.addTab(...);
    tabHost.addTab(...);
    return view;
}
```